# wso2 IS 5.0 SP1 : session persistence

Tags: session, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 Is 5.0 sp1. We are using the session persistence feature where we have given the following config

```
 <SessionDataPersist>
 <Enable>true</Enable>
 <RememberMePeriod>30</RememberMePeriod>
 <CleanUp>
 <Enable>true</Enable>
  <Period>5</Period>
 <TimeOut>35</TimeOut>
 </CleanUp>
<Temporary>false</Temporary>
</SessionDataPersist>
```

Our observation is that after 15 min of session inactivity wso2 IS time-outs. This means that even after specifying session persistence of higher value the session still timesout after 15 min of inactivity in wso2 IS. From the name of the property  I feel that we need to set the remember me on the login page. Is this true?
Thanks in advance

Cijoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. By default, idle timeout of SSO session is set to 15min.  But you can configure the idle timeout using following property in `/repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml` file.

`<session-timeout>15</session-timeout>`

However; i assume that there may be some issue with WSO2IS 5.0.0 SP1. It is not working as expected way with regarding session time. There seems be some bugs with it.  Hope; it will be release SP2 with these fixes. But i guess it is better to try 5.1.0 which is going to release soon.  Please find more details about session time out from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/10/15/how-to-configure-session-time-out-in-wso2-identity-server-wso2is/)

Comment: any idea when is 5.1 going to be released?